# What does this error mean and how do I fix it? "make: *** [lexer] Error 127"

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, compiler-errors, yacc

I'm an absolute beginner so please understand that when you reply.

I'm running the latest version of gcc 4.8.2 and I followed these instruction on installing lax http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/ope...untu_linux.php

I am running this on a virtual box

Comment: Your link is incorrect. Also, consider adding more information to your question. What step did you reach before you met this error?

Answer (score 1):

The message "`make: *** [lexer] Error 127`" means that make was trying to build a target called "lexer" and the command run to (re)build the target failed with an exit code of 127.

As to how you fix it, it's most likely a problem with your setup (some necessary tool or package is missing).  Exactly what is impossible to say without more context.